# When will SetupUninstallOEMInf return ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS?

Tags: windows, device-driver, setupapi

Under what circumstances does SetupAPI's `SetupUninstallOEMInf` function set the `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` error code?

The MSDN documentation does not detail this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` error code can indicate there are still installed devices using this .INF file (and the `SUOI_FORCEDELETE` flag wasn't specified).

Reading `%windir%\setupapi.log` (on XP) or `%windir%\Inf\setupapi.dev.log` (on Vista and higher) can be helpful to determine what SetupAPI is really trying to say.